# ant javadoc does not build

Tags: java, ant

This is my first java project deploying ant. I have to submit my code soon and do not have time for Hello World sort of thing for Ant. I tried to make a build.xml for my project after doing a bit of google but now i am stuck!

The ant javadoc does not work for me. Below is the error it displays when given the command : ant javadoc -debug

```
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor

BUILD FAILED
Target "javadoc" does not exist in the project "Ant-Test".
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.tsort(Project.java:1912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1820)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.topoSort(Project.java:1783)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

the package under which i have created all my four classes

```
package org.acrusys.customers;
```

and last but not the least below is the directory structure

```
Directory of C:\Users\Salman\JavaWorkspace\Arcusys\src\org\acrusys\customers

04/11/2012  07:40 PM    <DIR>          .
04/11/2012  07:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/11/2012  06:20 PM               757 AllCustomers.class 
04/11/2012  12:22 PM               520 AllCustomers.java
04/11/2012  07:40 PM    <DIR>          build
04/11/2012  07:30 PM             1,746 build.xml
04/11/2012  03:09 PM    <DIR>          classes
04/11/2012  06:20 PM             1,470 Customer.class
04/11/2012  05:27 PM             1,456 Customer.java
04/11/2012  06:20 PM             1,396 CustomerFullAddress.class
04/10/2012  11:55 PM             1,343 CustomerFullAddress.java
04/11/2012  06:20 PM             2,890 CustomerMain.class
04/11/2012  06:19 PM             2,392 CustomerMain.java
04/11/2012  07:40 PM    <DIR>          dist
04/11/2012  07:40 PM    <DIR>          docs
04/11/2012  06:55 PM    <DIR>          src
```

Here is the Javadoc (i forget to paste it initially)

```
<target name="docs" depends="compile">
<javadoc packagenames="org.acrusys.customers.*" sourcepath="${src.dir}"    destdir="${docs.dir}">
<!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
<include name="**" />
</fileset>
</javadoc>
</target>
```

Comment: There is no target '`javadoc`' in your project. (Why not post relevant content to question?)

Comment: @ LivingThing : Why are the .class files in same directory as sources?  They should be under some different directory(say, build/classes ).

Comment: How is that "javadoc"? Also, use the code formatting provided by the site, and indent.

Comment: my bad, thanks dave for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) is normally associated with documentation that you write into your code in the form of comments, and is automatically extracted out into HTML Files.

Try running: ant jar

The target you specified in your build file is "jar".   This will not fix all of your problems, as I can't see your compile target.  It also seems like your source code is in the wrong place (It should be located in the src directory, under the correct package structure), and the built .class files are also not ending up in the build directory.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing:

```
$ ant javadoc
```

or

```
$ ant docs
```

You're target name is `docs` and not `javadoc`. You should be doing the latter.

Comment: thanks..thats the bad part of doing thing in a hurry, anyways now i have started to organize my class and source file first as mentioned in the post above after that will keep your point in mind before seeing if it works then..

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me. I am giving here only target you need to use this target.

```
<target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>
```

After running this target you will get all documents into your doc folder.