# cannot create the javaDoc

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

Hi I have my main method in a class name Assignment1 and the package name is defined as

```
package assignment1;
```

I'm trying to make the javaDoc from the ant build. my build file has

```
<target name="javadoc" depends="init" description="creates javadoc">
  <javadoc sourcepath="."  destdir="DOCS"/>
  </target>
```

and when I run it I get the error Assignment1 contains source files in the default package, you must specify them as source files not packages.
build and java files are in the same folder please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, you must specify .java files rather than a path, since your classes are not declared to be in any package.  Inside your `<javadoc>` element, try adding a `<fileset>`:

```
<javadoc destdir="DOCS">
    <fileset dir="."/>
</javadoc>
```

From the [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) for nested filesets in the `<javadoc>` task:

> All matched files will be passed to javadoc as source files. Ant will automatically add the include pattern `**/*.java` to these filesets.
>   Nested filesets can be used to document sources that are in the default package.

Comment: Hi VGR, thank you for the reply I tried that too. but it gave me an error saying "No source files and no packages have been specified." do I have to give the package name somewhere? thanx again

Comment: VGR actually your answer worked I haven't closed one tag that's why I got this error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have a post on ANT Javadoc creation, in the following link.

You can try the answer where a sample target is given.

[ant javadoc does not build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110517/ant-javadoc-does-not-build)

Cheers.